# Own math symbols

Tags: symbols

I'm not professionalist on latex and I need help. 
I don't know how to create two sybols: 
[image]

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please indicate what these symbols are supposed to represent. Just plain old symbols, math operators, or something else? Please advise.

Comment: For those voting to close the question, I would note two things: 1) the OP didn't ask what the symbol was, but rather how to create it, and 2) I've long felt it should be incumbent on those who cite https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character as the pretext to close to at least know or be confident that the symbol in question *actually exists* in some other LaTeX format. Given that the OP called these his "own math symbols", it is certainly possible that they do not exist in other settings, except at your local VW dealership.

Comment: The packages `MnSymbol` and `fdsymbol` provide macros called `\doublevee` and `\doublewedge`, respectively. To be sure, depending on your document setup, using the `MnSymbol` package may not be a good idea for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By taking Mico's answer and running it through the `scalerel` package's `\hstretch`, we both can compress it horizontally a little and automatically make it work across the smaller mathstyles

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\vvee{\hstretch{.8}{\vee\mkern-8mu\vee}}       % "double vee"
\newcommand\wwedge{\hstretch{.8}{\wedge\mkern-8mu\wedge}} % "double wedge"

\begin{document}
$\vvee\quad\wwedge$

$\scriptstyle\vvee\quad\wwedge$

$\scriptscriptstyle\vvee\quad\wwedge$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The following code might be a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\vvee{{\vee\mkern-8mu\vee}}       % "double vee"
\newcommand\wwedge{{\wedge\mkern-8mu\wedge}} % "double wedge"

\begin{document}
$\vvee$ $\wwedge$
\end{document}
```